# Accessing main() functions from another javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have this issue where i have 2 files 
1) containing main() and other stuff related to the main UI
inside main() there are some functions
2) another file that makes the connection from the server to the UI

I am unable to find any solution to call functions from main() from the secondary file ( I know this is not a godd programming-design but i've already written a lot of code)

Thanks:)

Comment: We cannot really help you without some example code. If the other functions are defined inside the `main` function, then you cannot access the from the other file because they are not in global scope.

Comment: Is main part of window? As in `window.main()` ? or a regular `function main()` invocation?

Comment: You totally can use a "main()" function declared in another file if : They have the same scope (usually the global one) and if the one you attempt to call already exists (loading the file in the right order)

Comment: That's still not helpful... please **edit your question** and provide a **concrete example**. Clearly indicate where a function is defined and where you are trying to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In js, `function`s are your scope constraints. So, consider the following code:

```
function main(){
    function callMom(){
        alert('hi mom!');
    }
}

function goAboutYourDay(){
    brushTeeth(); // works
    callMom(); // wont work
}

function brushTeeth(){
    alert('brush brush brush');
}
```

Given your situation, you might consider returning some of main's functions like this:

```
function main(){
    var callMom = function(){ 
        alert('hi mom!');
    }

    return {
        callMommy: callMom
    };
}

function goAboutYourDay(){
    var m = main();
    m.callMommy(); 
}
```

Here's how you would do it with prototypes:

```
var Main = function(){
    this.message = "Will you send some candy?";
};

Main.prototype.callMom = function(){
    alert('Hi Mom! ' + this.message);
};

function otherFile(){
    // you could create a new instance of Main if there isn't one available to you here
    var main = new Main(); 
    main.callMom();    
}

otherFile();
​
```

Here are a few jsfiddles so that you can play with these examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/A3dSB/
http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/FyDAL/
http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/2TLu2/

Comment: So my program is basically made of functions callMom() ; So there's no way i can call that function ; Thanks

Comment: @VladStoica See my edits above! You should be able to `callMom()` all you want! :)

Comment: Basically, you get to decide in your design which functions you want to make callable. Put them in the global scope, or return an object with the function as a property. If you nest the function and don't provide an interface to call it, then it's private. This is the kludgey way to do "modules" in JS.

Comment: @VladStoica No problem. Just remember that everytime you call `main()` to get that return object, `main` is executing. You might have code in there that you don't want to be running every time...

Comment: @VladStoica you should hit the checkbox next to this answer if it answered your question